# Exchanging data between web sites

Tags: java, php, data-sharing

What is the most practical way of exchanging data between web sites (format, medium, protocol ...) ?

For example say an open-source online game has been designed such that each site where it's installed acts as a separate world. How would you go about transferring the profile of a character between two sites?

Comment: As Samus_ pointed out, I'm not sure this is the correct place to ask that...

Comment: @VicentePlata Understood :) . You or another user are free to move this a more convenient stack exchange site.

Answer (score 2):

this is a generic question so it probably belongs somewhere else, regardless what you normally do is to provide an API for external non-human clients to communicate, the details of it are completely up to you but the current popular choice is to make a [RESTful API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) and use [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) as the serialization format.

Comment: Ok. I'll post at the programmer's stack exchange for questions like this in future. So REST and JSON is the way to go. I suppose I could add a key during requests to limit access.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use web service to exchange data between web sites.In web world web service  soap is global format which is understand by all web framwork like php,asp,dotnet and other web framworks

Answer (score 0):

open-API maybe the bast way. Because your website client is more and more.
And send each website a code.check the code in your online game and the request times every day.